# PySpark - While reading a JSON file with read.format('json'), DataFrame just includes very first row. Why is this happening?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I am reading from a JSON file with this format:

```
{"username": "robert87", "currency": "BZD", "amount": 143472}
{"username": "taylorrobert", "currency": "TZS", "amount": 183074}
{"username": "ascott", "currency": "LRD", "amount": 154351}
{"username": "julie29", "currency": "JPY", "amount": 128404}
{"username": "rachelrogers", "currency": "CUP", "amount": 46338}
{"username": "tiffanyschmidt", "currency": "GBP", "amount": 88392}
```

Despite the JSON files includes 6 lines, when I run the following:

```
df = spark.read.format('json').load('file.json')

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I only get back the very first row:

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
amount:long
currency:string
username:string
Session created
root
 |-- amount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- username: string (nullable = true)

+------+--------+--------+
|amount|currency|username|
+------+--------+--------+
|143472|     BZD|robert87|
+------+--------+--------+
```

Why can't I see all the other records in the appropriate columns? Is it a problem related to the format I am using?

Answer (score 0):

I can see all the rows , try below

```
df = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/a_json.json")
df.show()
+------+--------+--------------+
|amount|currency|      username|
+------+--------+--------------+
|143472|     BZD|      robert87|
|183074|     TZS|  taylorrobert|
|154351|     LRD|        ascott|
|128404|     JPY|       julie29|
| 46338|     CUP|  rachelrogers|
| 88392|     GBP|tiffanyschmidt|
+------+--------+--------------+
```